# How to configure QGIS Web Client?

Tags: qgis-server, qgis-web-client

I need to use QGIS Web-client to publish a research project on web.
I setup the software on Windows and on Ubuntu Linux, changing the configuration as described in the README file and replacing the qgis_mapserv.fcgi with the server for the correct platform.

Now I have the client on Windows which isn't working at all. On Linux I can load the helloworld.qgs example, but I see the dreaded pink screen.
The 'natural' map is not loading, it keep going forever and without no one connection with the server.

The QGIS server is working correctly on Windows and not really in a good way on Linux, but it doesn't matter. I need a working configuration for one system, OS independent.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for Ubuntu 12.04

1. configure Qgis server following this useful [post](http://anitagraser.com/category/gis/qgis-server/);
2. copy your qgis project directory in /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ as explained above;
3. download qgis client from [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Web-Client)
4. follow the README file to configure and to put the client in action; (I have copied it in my www directory);
5. access your project with this kind of basic URL:

> localhost/your-own-path-to/site/qgiswebclient.html?map=/usr/lib/cgi-bin/your-project-directory/your-project.qgs

Comment: And here's the answer for 14.04 http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109967/qgis-server-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-permission-denied