# Integrate QGIS Server with existing Wordpress installation

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, apache, wordpress

How can I integrate QGIS Server with an existing worpdress installation?

I have tried but cannot get capabilities to appear. Maybe something to do with Htaccess or httpd.conf but I cannot understand...

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: have an existing wordpress site and an existing map server. Would like to have all hosted from one domain name. This seemed like the logical way to do it

Comment: ah gotcha - thought you wanted something more complex... glad you found the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Found my answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109967/qgis-server-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-permission-denied)

With an existing wordpress installation  I can just follow:

http://anitagraser.com/2012/03/30/qgis-server-on-ubuntu-step-by-step/

key change is to append within /etc/apache2/apache.conf the following:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/">
Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
Require all granted
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
</Directory>
```

job done. all happy.