# QGIS Server, GetCapabilities not working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: qgis

I've spent a couple of days now troubleshooting a QGIS Server setup in Ubuntu 14.04.

**I am following this guide to install QGIS server:**
http://anitagraser.com/2012/03/30/qgis-server-on-ubuntu-step-by-step/

According to the guide above, the installation should respond to the request below.
`wget -p -O - "http://localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities"`

All I am getting is a 404. Apache 2 and FCGID are installed and enabled. I seem to be missing something.

I've tried the setup with 2.8LTR and 2.14LTR both unsuccessfully, but unable to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

solved the issue by adding the following lines to the `000-default.conf` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

`ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/">
Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
Require all granted
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
</Directory>`

I got the solution from this thread
[Qgis server on Ubuntu Server 14.04: Permission denied](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109967/qgis-server-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-permission-denied?rq=1)